# Cannot install package `libxerces27-dev` when installing `phc` php compiler

Tags: php, ubuntu, compiler-construction, package, ubuntu-11.04

To install `phc` following this [guide](http://www.phpcompiler.org/doc/latest/install.html) in Ubuntu Oneiric 11.04, I get error saying that the package is not available as below screenshot.

Searching for the package at ubuntu's package search page result in no luck for me.

[image]

Comment: Closed as TL because once the documentation is updated, well, this question/answer pair becomes pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @casperOne still waiting...  btw, this question helped me.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like ubuntu has changed since I wrote that. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libxerces-c-dev
```

(Contributing the change to the phc documentation would be very welcome)

Comment: Thank you! It's so honor to talk with you directly here! How would I contribute to the document? I'm willing to do so.

Comment: @NamGiVU Edit the files in the docs/ directory, write a patch, send the patch to the mailing list and I'll give you write access :)

Comment: `write a patch` <- what is a patch? Should I need only update the file and mail the change?